# Apache2 not restarting on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-9.10

I have installed apache 2 in ubuntu but when i try to restart it gives me this error

```
vmware@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Mon Apr 12 17:37:43 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Mon Apr 12 17:37:43 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

When i try `http://localhost`

Now i get this error

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ubuntu
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ubuntu
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open log
```

s

nothing comes

```
This is the netstat output


Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:3389                  *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:3350          *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 localhost:postgresql    [::]:*                  LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:microsoft-ds       [::]:*                  LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5900               [::]:*                  LISTEN      1338/vino-server
```

and restarting apache now gives

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ubuntu
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting .apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ubuntu
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing a VirtualHost section even though you have a NameVirtualHost declaration in your configuration.

You either need to remove the NameVirtualHost line, or fix your virtual host configuration.

EDIT: With respect to your latest update - this means something else is running on port 80, and so Apache can't listen for connections on that port. You may have some other daemon (or perhaps a rogue Apache process) running.

You can run `netstat --tcp --listening --programs` to show all listening sockets as well as the application listening on each port. You'll be looking for `*:www` or `*:80` in the "Local Address" column. Once you know the application listening on port 80, you can determine the best method of solving the problem.

Comment: I have not added any vitual host , its just the fresh install of ubuntu. How can fix that

Comment: `sudo a2ensite default` might fix an error in the default setup of Apache on Ubuntu. Alternatively, remove the `NameVirtualHost *:80` line in /etc/apache2/ports.conf.

Answer (score 1):

> apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName

Edit `/etc/hostname` or use a ServerName directive if you don't need to serve multiple websites on a single machine to fix that error.

To hit up the rest of the errors, look at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for your configuration. There should be a default site just serving up `/var/www`.

Comment: yes there are two default sites , 000-default and other is matrix , what should i do next

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [Setting Up Name Based Virtual Hosting](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/09/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting/).

To find out what else is tying up port 80, run this:

```
netstat -lnp | grep :80
```

Then you can do something like `killall -9 [process-name]` and try restarting again.

Comment: I tried all nestat commands but i see nothing running on port 80